# To be able to show a list of items next to each other with no definite number of columns

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to list item in the column such that when the list item reaches max. height then it moves to the next column automatically

I have got a row with two columns

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-3">
</div>
<div class="col-md-9">
 // -- <li item
</div>
```

I want to list items 1,2,3 in one column and then it moves to column. However, I cannot hard code number of columns, because it will be dynamic that item 5 needs more space and then item 6 will come to the next column.

```
Item 1     Item4   Item6
Item 2     Item5   Item7
Item 3
```

Comment: Some fiddle example?

Answer (score 0):

There is a CSS3 feature named `column-count` that you can use. Check this code and snippet:

```css
.three-col-list {
  -webkit-column-count: 3;
  -moz-column-count: 3;
  column-count: 3;
  height: 250px;
}

.three-col-list li {
  display: block;
  padding: 0 10px 60px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="three-col-list">
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
  <li>Item 4</li>
  <li>Item 5</li>
  <li>Item 6</li>
  <li>Item 7</li>
  <li>Item 8</li>
  <li>Item 9</li>
</ul>
```

While this doesn't use the Bootstrap column classes, I'm sure you can get it styled with custom classes and some padding that Bootstrap uses. Note that this is not supported by IE9 or older.

Comment: This is not even aligned , each row is not perfect like the question is asking

Comment: What do you mean with each row is not perfect? You just set the height of the list and it adds items to one column until that height is reached, just like OP was asking.

Answer (score -1):

If you want that columns be fluid with any amount of items being dynamically added you can try keeping all the items in one div row like this :-

```
  <!doctype html>
  <html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>My Website</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
 <div class="row" > 
            <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4" style="background-color: #dedef8; box-shadow: inset 1px -1px 1px #444, inset -1px 1px 1px #444;"> 
               <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. 
                </p> 
            </div> 
            <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4" style="background-color: #dedef8;box-shadow: inset 1px -1px 1px #444, inset -1px 1px 1px #444;"> 
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. 
                </p> 
            </div> 

            <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4" style="background-color: #dedef8; box-shadow:inset 1px -1px 1px #444, inset -1px 1px 1px #444;"> 
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. 
                </p> 
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4" style="background-color: #dedef8; box-shadow: inset 1px -1px 1px #444, inset -1px 1px 1px #444;"> 
               <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. 
                </p> 
            </div> 
            <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4" style="background-color: #dedef8;box-shadow: inset 1px -1px 1px #444, inset -1px 1px 1px #444;"> 
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. 
                </p> 
            </div> 

            <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4" style="background-color: #dedef8; box-shadow:inset 1px -1px 1px #444, inset -1px 1px 1px #444;"> 
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. 
                </p> 
            </div> 

        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here the column will overflow and adjust to next line if the content increases.

Comment: This is not even close to what he is asking . the elements needs to be generated dynamically and calculated 2 on each row . you are simply hardcoding all the values

Comment: Before downgrading my answer and giving your supposed "solution". Have you even read the question?He has asked for solution involving twitter-bootstrap not some simple CSS3. Your solution is not at all he asked for as it breaks when screen size is decreased or increased. While my solution doesn't break irrespective of screen size. I hardcoded as he never mentioned which language he need the solution apart from css.

Answer (score -1):

You have to dynamically generate the element and append to the div

> DEMO : http://jsfiddle.net/cryzfcL8/7/

```
<div id="col1"></div>
<div id="col2"></div>
<div id="col3"></div>

      var data=["item1","item2","item3","item4","item5","item6","item7","item8",
          "item9"];
                var j=0;
                var k=1;
                for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
                    if(j<3){
                        j++;
                        var elem = document.createElement('p');
                        elem.innerHTML =data[i];  
                        console.log(elem);
                        document.getElementById('col'+k).appendChild(elem);

                    }else{
                        j=0;
                        k=k+1;
                    }

                }

 #col2{
     margin-left:10%;
     display:inline;
     margin-top:-19%;
     position:absolute;
 }
 #col3{
     margin-left:20%;
     display:inline;
     margin-top:-19%;
     position:absolute;
 }
```